# Does my function violate SRP or other best practices?

Tags: c#, refactoring, single-responsibility-principle

I have this following piece of code, a function that will get a list of objects ( I call it Y Objects) and call another method to transform it into X Objects.

```
public List<X> GetXObjects()
{
    var yObjects= GetYObjects();
    var transformer = new Transformer();
    var xObjects = transformer.Transform(yObjects);
    return xObjects;
}
```

The current implementation works, however, I feel that my function may violate SRP or other best practices. Is it possible to refactor the code to be better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call the method `TransformObjects` and add the the transformer as parameter so it is possible to use different transformers and the transformer is not initialized each time you call the method. The same for the `yObjects`. So the only responsibility of the method is to transform your objects.

```
public List<X> TransformObjects(List<Y> yObjects, Transformer transformer)
{
    var xObjects = transformer.Transform(yObjects);
    return xObjects;
}
```

call of the method:

```
var yObjects= _crmWrapper.GetActivitiesByOpportunities();
var transformer = new Transformer();
myTransformer.TransformObjects(yObjects, transformer);
```

If you create an interface `ITransformer` interface it would be easier to enhance your code by exchanging the transformer.

Comment: Good answer, but, if you take it down this path, why reinvent the wheel? There is no need for `TransformObjects`, `Enumerable.Select` does the job already (see my answer for details).

Comment: @InBetween a very good hint! I wanted to explain how the SRP could be achieved in general -> not by using `Enumerable.Select`.

Answer (score 2):

My two cents of worth...

I would make this code a lot more general at little cost. Expanding on [Kevin Wallis' good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45139447/767890), why not go ahead and simply remove this pesky transformer? Anything that knows how to transform `Y` to `X` should do, right?

And why accept and return a `List`? Let the consumer decide if he wants to consume the enumeration eagerly or not, don't make the decision for him unless its necessary.

```
public IEnumerable<TResult> TransformObjects<TResult, TSource>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> transformer)
    => source.Select(transformer);
```

And now suddenly you realize; hey! this just a regular good old `Enumerable.Select`, isn't it? Then, why reinvent the wheel?

```
var xObjects = GetYObjects().Select(transformer.Transform);
```

So your code is finally an `Enumerable.Select`! Great, no bugs here and one method less I need to test, move on ;).

Answer (score 1):

Your function do next tasks

- load activities
- create instance of transformer
- transform loaded objects

Load of activities can be removed by introduced it as argument

```
public List<X> GetXObjects(List<Y> yObjects)
{
    var transformer = new Transformer();
    return transformer.Transform(yObjects);
}
```

Then creation of transformer can be moved outside too

```
public List<X> GetXObjects(Trnasformer transformer, List<Y> yObjects)
{
    return transformer.Transform(yObjects);
}
```

So now some where inthe code you call it like this

```
var yObjects= _crmWrapper.GetActivitiesByOpportunities();
var transformer = new Transformer();
var xObjects = GetXObjects(yObjects, transformer);
```

But hits mean every where where you need load `XObjects` you need toknow how to load `YObjects` and how to create `Transformer`

So we can encapsulate this knowledge/logic in one class

```
public class XObjectsProvider
{

}
```

This class should load `YObjects` and transform them to XObject. Actual implementation of loading and creation of Transform instance not responsibility of this class - so we introduce them as dependencies.

```
public class XObjectsProvider
{
    private Loader _loader;
    private Transformer _transformer;

    public XObjectsProvider(Loader loader, Transformer transformer)
    {
        _loader = loader;
        _transformer = transformer;
    }

    public XObjects Get()
    {
        var yObjects = _loader.GetYObjects();
        return transformer.Transform(yObjects);
    }
}
```

`Loader` and `Transformer` can be introduced as abstractions and which give you possibility to change them without changing code of `XObjectProvider` - following "Open/Close principle".
And `XObjectProvider` have only one reason to change - when for getting XObjects you need to load/provide something other information.